# Why is autosize function setting the size of width wrong?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm programmatically creating labels and a textbox beside it.

To create the textbox beside it I use the following calculation to determine the Location.X for the textbox:
label2.X+label2.Width+5;

Here's the issue; the label gets created and I have autosize turned on for it, then after enter the text it sizes appropriately. However, the textbox does not get created besides it but it overlapping it for some distance.

I debugged my code and the label was returning the width of 100, while after creating a duplicate label manually with autosize on and same string of text the width came to be 149. Why is this problem there and is there a solution to it other than manually doing it every time there's a problem?

My code below:

```
//Qd
                //label
                Label label2 = new Label();
                label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 68);
                label2.Name = "label2";
                //label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 13);
                label2.TabIndex = 16;
                label2.Text = "Characteristic Strength Qd:";
                label2.AutoSize = true;
                label2.MouseHover += new EventHandler(BoucWen_Qd_MouseHover);
                //textbox
                TextBox textBox3 = new TextBox();
                textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(/*90*/149+5+6, 65);
                textBox3.Name = "Qd";
                textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(197, 20);
                textBox3.TabIndex = 17;
                textBox3.Tag = "Characteristic Strength\r\n Link: )_Element";
                textBox3.HelpRequested += new HelpEventHandler(Node_label1_HelpRequested);
                //create units label 
                x_unit = textBox3.Location.X + textBox3.Width + 5;
                y_unit = textBox3.Location.Y;
                labelUnit = new Label();
                labelUnit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x_unit, y_unit);
                labelUnit.AutoSize = true;
                labelUnit.Text = forceunit;
                Fixidity_panel.Controls.Add(labelUnit); 

//adding the above two label&textbox:
 Fixidity_panel.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {

                     comboBox2,
                     label11,
                     textBox11,
                     label10,
                     comboBox1,
                     label9,
                     textBox9,
                     label8,
                     textBox8,
                     label7,
                     textBox7,
                     label6,
                     textBox6,
                     label5,
                     textBox5,
                     label4,
                     textBox4,
                     label3,
                    textBox3,
                     label2,
                     textBox2,
                     Stiffness_label, });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `AutoSize` property is set to true the calculation of the width will be proceeded only after it will be added to the panel.
 hence, you should first add it to the panel and then add the texbox and set its location `.Location = label2.Location.X+label2.Width +5` to get the expected result.
 here is my suggestion, based on your code:

(please read my comments written in CAPITAL letters)

```
//label
Label label2 = new Label();
label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 68);
label2.Name = "label2";
//label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 13);
label2.TabIndex = 16;
label2.Text = "Characteristic Strength Qd:";
label2.AutoSize = true;
// ADD IT TO THE PANEL IN ORDER TO GAIN A WIDTH
Fixidity_panel.Controls.Add(label2);
label2.MouseHover += new EventHandler(BoucWen_Qd_MouseHover);
//textbox
TextBox textBox3 = new TextBox();
// NOW YOU CAN DO:  .Location = label2.X+label2.Width+5
textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(label2.Location.X+label2.Width +5, 65);
textBox3.Name = "Qd";
textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(197, 20);
textBox3.TabIndex = 17;
textBox3.Tag = "Characteristic Strength\r\n Link: )_Element";
// NOW ADD THE TEXTBOX
Fixidity_panel.Controls.Add(textBox3);
```